# My iPad is Plugged Right Into My Computer - How To Visit my Computer's Localhost?

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, testing

I have a simple server running on my Windows 7 based computer at `localhost:9000` that ouputs    `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`

My iPad is plugged into my computer directly via the USB charging cable. iTunes recognizes that it is there.

How do I navigate to the Hello World page from my iPad?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general hardware tech support. And I seriously double Apple would have enabled TCP-over-USB anyways, since that'd actually make ipads somewhat useful, and Apple does not want their "mobile" products used for useful things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure it's possible because the Ipad is not part of the system itself.

You could try bridging the connection through your network settings, that may work.